# Rescale Angular Chart.js when col-size is changed

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am currently working on a dashboard using angular.js and [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). I like to show X-number of chart.js charts (added by clicking on "Add Chart"-button), and want to set Y-number (must be between 1-4) of charts for each row (selected by the dropdown, for this example Y=4). See picture attached bellow (not pretty, I know..): 
[image]

This is working, but the problem is when changing from the Y-value. For example: when Y=4 to Y=1, then it will look like something like this: 
[image]
How do I scale the chart properly when clicking on the dropdown?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-default biggerbutton add-chart-button' ng-click="addChart()"> Add Chart </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default">{{graphPrRow.text}}</a>
            <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <li ng-repeat="op in graphPrRow.options" ng-click="clickDropdownGraphsPrRow(); graphPrRow.selected = op.col_size"><a>{{op.value}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="graphPrRow.selected" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row>
                         <canvas id="chart.id" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="chart.data" chart-labels="chart.labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="chart.series" chart-options="chart.options"</canvas>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$scope.graphPrRow = { selected: "", options: [{value: 1, col_size: "col-md-12"}, {value: 2, col_size: "col-md-6"}, {value: 3, col_size: "col-md-4"}, {value: 4, col_size: "col-md-3"}], text: 'to be written.. ' };

$scope.addChart = function () {
    chartId ++;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.charts.push({ id: chartId, labels: label, series: [], data: [], options: { animation: false, responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false } });
    });
};

$scope.clickDropdownGraphsPrRow = function () {
    //TODO
};
```

Comment: Are you using chart.js or angular-chart?

Comment: I am using angular-chart.js (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) ;)

Comment: For most of chart library, you need to get the reference of the chart, and then call `redraw()` or `resize()` method. Check this issue on angular-chart.js github. https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/118